# weblogic EJB status is showing 0 threads

Tags: weblogic

I have an EJB deployed to weblogic server with no issues while deploying. When I looked at the admin console the status is showing active. But run the service it say this EJB is "Running with 0 threads".

Comment: Does the service work? Have you tried calling it? Can you hit a WSDL with your browser? There is not enough details to help...

Comment: I can hit WSDL from the browser, in the weblogic logs there is additional error message that I can see : INFO: Notifier: NotifierEJB started...
Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.<name>.notifier.NotifierThread.run(NotifierThread.java:264)

Comment: It's working and for the record I cleaned up the message queue from services --> JMS Module